# I have Installed, appium and the driver as well but I am struggling

Tags: selenium-webdriver, appium-android, android-uiautomator

I have installed Appium. UIautomator 2 driver also added dependencies for all of the required tools but I am getting an exception named as

```
Unable to create a new remote session. Please check the server log for more details. Original error: The requested resource could not be found, or a request was received using an HTTP method that is not supported by the mapped resource (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 184 milliseconds
```

I am posting my code as well

[Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vlFRV.png)

I am trying to run Appium but Its not working already I have installed android studio, everything I tried but its not happening first tine I am trying StackOverflow for the support

Comment: you have 2 points to look into. 1 the selenium-client on java testcode, 2 the appium server interacting with the app. so i assume u started the appium server manually. and where do you see this exception, java client or appium server

Comment: I am starting appium from terminal and all the jar  file are already added in POM.XML

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to know the exact reason for your issue but you can try the following things.

- Check if your internet is working correctly
- Check Appium server port

  - If you are running tests on a physical device then use  4724
  - In the case of an emulator use port 4723
- Try re-installing the `UI Automator` driver and `Appium inspector`

I faced a similar type of error and fixed it by changing the Appium server port from **4723** to **4724**.